# Finding a model instance with no relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, relational-database, where-clause, belongs-to, has-one

```
class User
has_one :settings

class Settings
belongs_to :user
```

I want to do something like

```
@user_with_no_settings = User.where(:settings => nil)
```

But this returns an empty relation.

How do I find all users which don't have a settings related to them? (So I will find them and create them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most importantly, your association is incorrect;

Change it to:

```
class User
has_one :setting

class Settings
belongs_to :user
```

The Class name is plural but the association `has_one` is always singular. So you can't use `:settings` for `has_one` as oppose to `has_many` which is always plural.

Use this:

```
User.where("id not in (select user_id from settings)")
```

The above query will give all the users which don't have a settings associated to them.

Comment: why? the model name is Settings, not Setting

Comment: Refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. There is a section: `The has_one Association`

Answer (score 0):

Okay. In your situation you may need some TRY this code.

```
User.where('id NOT IN (?)', User.joins(:settings).pluck('settings.user_id'))
```

But, you need to follow Rails Convention.

Change settings to setting.